# OMNET++ IDE Vectors Plot Error

Tags: vector, plot, omnet++

I got a problem when plot the vectors in the .anf file.

When I work with small number of nodes, it works normally and I can plot the vectors (simulation time might arrive until 1000s).
But when the number of nodes is big  (for example 50 nodes), I can not plot the vectors specially when simulation time is big ( more than 250s, i can't plot)  and It always alerts: 
"Evaluating dataset... has encountered a problem. An error occurred 
during the dataset processing.

I use omnet++ 4.2

Please help me,
best regards

Comment: If the .vec file your are loading is very large, maybe you are running out of memory. You can also try using a different program for plotting. I can recommend [using R to plot OMNeT++ simulation results](https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp-resultfiles/wiki/Tutorial-for-the-omnetpp-r-package)

Comment: I never use another  program for plotting  but I'll try it. I hope it works.